# Out Of Memory Exception when zipping memory stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage, memorystream

I have a text box that a user can submit a list of document ids to download those files zipped up from an Azure blob.

How the code currently functions building a zip memory stream and then for each document id submitted we build a memory stream, get the file from that stream, and then add it to the zip file. The issue is that we we are building the memory stream and getting a file that is larger than 180 mb the program throws an out of memory exception.

There is the code

```
public async Task<byte[]> BuildZipStream(string valueDataUploadContainerName, IEnumerable<Document> docs)
        {

            var zipMemStream = new MemoryStream();

            using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zip = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
            {
                zip.Name = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
                var insertedEntries = new List<string>();

                foreach (var doc in docs)
                {
                    var EntryName = $"{doc.Name}{Path.GetExtension(doc.DocumentPath)}";
                    if (insertedEntries.Contains(EntryName))
                    {
                        EntryName = $"{doc.Name} (1){Path.GetExtension(doc.DocumentPath)}";
                        var i = 1;
                        while (insertedEntries.Contains(EntryName))
                        {
                            EntryName = $"{doc.Name} ({i.ToString()}){Path.GetExtension(doc.DocumentPath)}";
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                    insertedEntries.Add(EntryName);
                    var file = await GetFileStream(blobFolderName, doc.DocumentPath);
                    if (file != null)
                        zip.AddEntry($"{EntryName}", file);
                }

                zip.Save(zipMemStream);
            }

            zipMemStream.Seek(0, 0);
            return zipMemStream.ToArray();
```

And then for actually getting the file from the blob storage

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetFileStream(string container, string filename)
        {

            var blobStorageAccount = _keyVaultService.GetSecret(new KeyVaultModel { Key = storageLocation });

            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(blobStorageAccount ?? _config.Value.StorageConnection);
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(container);

            await blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            var blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
            if (blockBlob.Exists())
            {
                using (var mStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(mStream);
                    mStream.Seek(0, 0);
                    return mStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
}
```

The problem occurs when the program hits `await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(mStream);` it will sit and spin for a while and then throw an out of memory exception.

I have read a few different solutions which have not been working for me, the most common being to change the Platform target under properties to be at least x64 and I am running this at x86. Another solution I could see would be to move the GetFileStream logic into the method for BuildZipStream, but then I feel the method would be doing too much.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
The problem is actually occurring when the program hits `zip.Save(zipMemStream)`

Comment: Are you sure it is the size of one file, and not the size of all the files still in memory?

Comment: Neithert the code `blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync()` nor the `blockBlob` variable are defined anywhere in that code.

Comment: Why do you go all way round to a byte[] array? Put the stream in the Zip directy: https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.AddEntry(string,%20System.IO.Stream)/

Comment: @Christopher I am. Even if I am only trying to get one file of that size or greater this still happens. As for your second comment I am confused. `.DownloadToStreamAsync()` and any of the class calls are from Microsoft `CloudStorageAccount` class

Comment: @DanByström because building the stream takes enough work that I believe it's beset handled in its own class

Comment: Without knowing what `blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync()` does, how are we suppsoed to guess what is going wrong in it to cause a OOM exception? We need a Minimal, Complete, Verifyable example. This is neither Minimal, nor Complete.

Comment: @Christopher so I guess that is one of my big problems. Once I hit any of those methods it's a black box. I cannot step through those methods.

Comment: @Freestob I am asuming those are not files with publically avalible documentation? If there is a documentation, please link it. If there is none, it is really up to the writer.

Comment: @Freestob " because building the stream takes enough work that I believe it's beset handled in its own class" - that strategy also consumes much much more memory - maybe you have to choose between good architecture and a working program :-)

Comment: Why in memory? Can you use a temporary file as your ‘buffer’ then return it, or its bytes, or better a strram to it, for download?

Answer (score -2):

Your methodology here is flawed. Because you do not know:

1. The Amount of Files.
2. The Size of Each File.

You cannot accurately determine if you'll have the memory in RAM within the server to actually HOUSE all the files in memory. What you are doing here is collecting every Azure Blob File they list and putting that into a Zip File IN MEMORY, while downloading each file IN MEMORY. It's no wonder you're getting a Out-Of-Memory exception, even with 128gb of RAM, if the user requests a big enough file, you'll Run out of Memory.

Your best solution, and the most common practice found with downloading and zipping multiple Azure Blob Files is to utilize a Temp Blob file.

Instead of writing to a MemoryStream, you write to FileStream and place that Zipped File onto the Azure Blob, and then Serve that zipped Blob File. Once the file is served you remove it from the Blob.

Hope this helps.